# The markup in the document following the root elemnt must be well formed

Tags: xml

I am getting following error line 2 on my XML document. Please help.

```
"The markup in the document following the root elemnt must be well formed."
```

My XML is

```
<property name="src" location="C:\Selenium\Workspace\AutoTester\src"/>
<property name="libs" location="C:\Selenium\Ref_Library"></property>
<property name="build" location="build"></property>

<!-- Define the classpath which includes the junit.jar and the classes after compiling--> 
<path id="AutoTester.classpath">
<pathelement location="bin"/>
<pathelement location="${libs}/jxl.jar"/>
<pathelement location="${libs}/selenium-java-srcs.jar"/>
<pathelement location="${libs}/selenium-java.jar"/>
<pathelement location="${libs}/selenium-server-standalone.jar"/>
<pathelement location="${libs}/testng.jar"/>
</path>

<!-- Deletes the existing build and result directories-->
<target name="clean">
<delete dir="${build}" />
</target>

<!-- Creates the build, and test results directories-->
<target name="makedir">
<mkdir dir="${build}" />
</target>

<!-- Compiles the java code -->
<target name="compile" depends="clean, makedir">
<javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${build}" debug="true" includeAntRuntime="false">
<classpath refid="AutoTester.classpath" />
</javac>
</target>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the root element is missing, or maybe you have not included the whole XML in your example. If it is an Ant script, as it looks, checkout the example at http://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html

Answer (score 2):

An XML file must always contain a single root element that contains all other elements. This looks like an Ant build script, meaning you forgot to wrap it inside a `<project>` element.

Comment: @Shweta: if it worked, please consider accepting this answer. If others were useful, consider upvoting them. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There must be a root element that contains the rest of the elements.

Just create one, for example:

```
<myXml>
    <property name="src" location="C:\Selenium\Workspace\AutoTester\src"/>

    <!-- Rest of your xml -->

</myXml>
```